# vlcj Mediastatistic does not show stats

Tags: java, kotlin, vlcj

I have been struggling with this for a very long time. I did not find information on the Internet on this issue. And I don't understand why the statistics aren't displayed. I stream videos from webcams.

```
0 - audioBuffersPlayed()
0 - decodedAudio()
0 - decodedVideo()
55.4688 - demuxBitrate()
-1308714496 - demuxBytesRead()
0 - demuxCorrupted()
0 - demuxDiscontinuity()
0.0 - inputBitrate()
0 - inputBytesRead()
0 - picturesDisplayed()
0 - picturesLost()
0.0 - sendBitrate()
0 - sentBytes()
0 - sentPackets()
```

My code:

```
class Stream(
    private val videoCodec: String,
    private val audioCodec: String,
    private val bitRate: Int,
    private val dr: DisplayResolution,
    private val protocol: String
) {

    private val mediaPlayerFactory: MediaPlayerFactory
    private val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

    private val isHttpProtocol: Boolean = protocol == "http"

    private var hwInfo: HardwareInfo = HardwareInfo()

    private val mediaStatistics = MediaStatistics()

    init {

        val media: String = "dshow://"  //"screen://" "dshow://"
        val deviseOptions: String = formatOptions()
        val streamOptions: String = formatRtspStream(deviseOptions, "localhost", 8080, "demo")

        mediaPlayerFactory = MediaPlayerFactory(media)
        mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newMediaPlayer()

        if (isHttpProtocol) {
            mediaPlayer.media().play(
                media,
                streamOptions,
            )
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.media().play(
                media,
                streamOptions,
                "encoding etc",
                ":no-sout-rtp-sap",
                ":no-sout-standard-sap",
                ":sout-all",
                ":sout-keep",
            )
        }

        TaskController.add(createTask(it), 1000L)
    }

    private fun formatOptions(): String {
        var options: String = ""
        options += ":sout=#transcode{"
        options += "vcodec=$videoCodec,"
        options += "vb=$bitRate,"
        options += "fps=25,"
        options += "scale=1,"
        options += "acodec=$audioCodec,"
        options += "ab=252," //128
        options += "channels=2,"
        options += "samplerate=44100,"
        options += "weight=${dr.weight},"
        options += "height=${dr.height}"
        options += "}"

        return options
    }

    private fun formatRtspStream(deviseOptions: String, serverAddress: String, serverPort: Int, id: String): String {
        return if (isHttpProtocol) "$deviseOptions:duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=$serverAddress:$serverPort}}"
        else "$deviseOptions:rtp{sdp=rtsp://@$serverAddress:$serverPort/$id}"
    }

private fun createTask(dc: DynamicChart): TimerTask {
        return timerTask {
            val info = mediaPlayer.media().info().statistics(mediaStatistics)
       
            println(mediaStatistics.sendBitrate())
            println(mediaStatistics.decodedAudio())
            println(mediaStatistics.demuxBitrate())
            println(mediaStatistics.inputBitrate())
            println(mediaStatistics.demuxDiscontinuity())
            // And so on...
        }
    }
```

"TaskContorller" Simply manages start / stop tasks.
I use the http or rtsp protocol. But in both cases only demuxBitrate is displayed from the statistics.
Streaming video is broadcast, and everything works fine except for statistics.
Please help me.

Comment: Sometimes statistics just aren't available.. To check if your code is correct, play a local file instead of a stream and see if stats get populated. If they do, then nothing is wrong with your code, and the stats simply aren't available. vlcj has a "StatsTest" example that works.

Comment: If, I broadcast a local file everything works, but my priority is to broadcast webcam.

Comment: So therefore what I'm saying is the stats code is working, but in the case of your webcam stream the stats are simply not available and there is nothing to be done about it.